# Introduction to algorithms

Tags: algorithm

How does reading the book Introduction to algorithms(CLRS) help me? How's learning this course connected with the other areas of theoretical computer science?(I mean intutions and insights if any that I could get).

I'm new to this concepts.I am getting bored of the sorting algorithms that I was learning in the course right now.I wanted to have a broader view while learning the course.It would be very helpful to me, if you could provide me with a structure on how things go.Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: What "other areas of theoretical computer science" are you thinking of that don't require a basic understanding of algorithm analysis?

Comment: Hello and welcome, you might find answers to these questions in the theoretical CS stackexchange site. StackOverflow is for practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face. See practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face

Answer (score 4):

Algorithms are the practical application of theoretical knowledge in computer science; they're the most theoretical part of the engineering side of computer science, so to speak. Without the study of algorithms, anyone in software would either be an amateur - because computation is useless without efficiency - or wouldn't produce much of anything since he would have to focus on solving problems all the time instead of actually writing implementations that are known to solve problems.

From a didactic point of view, algorithms are a distillation of theoretical knowledge into a precise expression. You may understand what graph traversal is and how strongly connected components should be contracted; if you try to give a succinct form to those thoughts, the best way to do it is writing down an algorithm that does what you want.

On a formal level, they help us understand the concepts we grapple with; when we claim some problem can be solved in this or that complexity, we need an algorithm to prove it. For example, if you read that sorting is in O(n log n) in the general case, you can just go ahead and believe your professor; maybe you even have an intuition why that might be true. But to actually prove it, you need an algorithm that solves sorting for which you then prove that it runs in O(n log n) in the general case. So on the theoretical level, algorithms help us classify problems according to their complexity (read: "difficulty").

Answer (score 1):

I'm not really sure that this question has a specific answer and that this is the right place to ask it, but it is still a useful one. Aside from trusting the people that have spent much of their lives guiding people to learn a skill set they will use for the rest of their lives (your professors), I have always looked at algorithm design as a way to learn how to think more clearly. This is something I believe everyone can learn from.

Also, when I was a student there were many times I was frustrated with what I was being asked to learn (believing that it is a waste). Virtually all of which I have found to be very useful and use frequently. Thinking back, I wish I had given some of my professors much more credit then I did when I was in school.